# Como solucionar um elseif que precisa ser exclusivo?

Tags: php, html, formulário

Quero criar uma página onde quando um *checkbox* esteja marcado, seja impresso uma mensagem, mas se todos os *checkbox* estiverem marcado, imprimir outra mensagem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Form de exemplo com checkboxes</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="bike" value="on">eu tenho uma bike
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="car" value="on">eu tenho um carro
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="RLRLRLRL" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?PHP
#$_POST['bike'] = ( isset($_POST['bike']) ) ? true : null;
#$_POST['car']  = ( isset($_POST['car']) )  ? true : null;
#var_dump($_POST);

$bike = $_POST['bike'];
$car = $_POST['car'];
if($bike) {
    echo "Olar, eu tenho uma bike";
} elseif ($car) {
    echo "Olar, eu tenho um carro";
} elseif ($car || $bike) {
    echo "Olar, eu tenho os dois";
}

?>
```

Comment: Tenho os dois, significa ambos, logo não é um `ou` e sim um `e`(&&)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesse caso específico as duas primeiras condições estão erradas, porque ela só deve ser executada se a possa é exclusiva, então a condição tem que garantir que ele não tem outra coisa. Há um erro na última porque imprimirá se tiver qualquer um dos dois, e não ambos, solução:

```
if ($bike && !$car) {
    echo "Olar, eu tenho uma bike";
} elseif ($car && !$bike) {
    echo "Olar, eu tenho um carro";
} elseif ($car && $bike) {
    echo "Olar, eu tenho os dois";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/IfElseIf.php).

Tem outras formas de resolver isto, mas esta é a mais próxima do que escreveu.

Comment: E na situação de eu ter vários itens ? Vou sempre ter que listar todos eles e ordenar manualmente (!$) ?

Comment: Aí a lógica provavelmente teria que ser diferente, eu respondi o que você perguntou, para outro problema, a resposta seria outra. Talvez a solução seja fazer algo bem diferente. Mas sempre é complicado dizer alguma coisa se os requisitos não estão bem definidos - e fazem sentido, claro. Já pensou que a frase do último não faz sentido? "Eu tenho os dois" o que? Isto não resolve um problema real.

Answer (score 3):

Como os valores dos checkboxs são os mesmos, outra maneira de resolver isso é combinar `array_keys()` para obter todas as chaves dos valores(`on`) encontrados, e verificar a quantidade com `count()`.

```
//equivalente os checkboxs marcados pelo $_POST
$itens = ['bike' => 'on', 'car' => 'on'];
//$itens = ['bike' => 'on']; //outro teste
$marcados = array_keys($itens, 'on');

if(count($marcados) === 1 ){
    echo 'eu tenho '. $marcados[0];
}else if(count($marcados) === 2){
    echo 'tenho ambos, bike e carro';
}
```

Comment: Eu também estou com a foto do cachorro agora ;)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters wow Doge, such shiba, very cutie. haha xD

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, outro dia vc tava falando do `array_keys()` olha ele ai, nesse caso, só pq os valores dos checkboxs são iguals ai trabalha com as chaves.

Comment: Bacana, @rray. +1